# WriteableBitmap performance: Debugging faster then Without Debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, desktop-application, .net-5

I have this code to measure the performance to draw a single pixel in a WriteableBitmap, and I notice in my system a considerable performance difference between these two starting modes, both in Release configuration.

When starting in Debugging, the speed is ~ 8.6K pixels/second, and when starting **without** Debugging ~ 2.6K. I was expecting the opposite

I wonder if I'm missing something or what is possible to do to achieve the same performance when starting in Debugging, or it is a bug.

```
class App1
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        new Window1().Show();
        new Application().Run();
    }
}

class Image1 : Image
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { }
}

class Window1 : Window
{
    WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap;
    Stopwatch clock1;
    long t1;
    int frames_counter;
    bool frame;
    int px;
    int py;
    Int32Rect single_pixel = new Int32Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    byte[] single_pixel_array;
    readonly byte[] red_collor = new byte[] { 0, 0, 255, 0 }; // B G R
    readonly byte[] blue_collor = new byte[] { 255, 0, 0, 0 }; // B G R

    public Window1()
    {
        Height = 150;
        Width = 350;
        Loaded += Window1_Loaded;
    }

    private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

        Content = new Image1
        {
            Stretch = Stretch.None,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            Source = writeableBitmap
        };

        single_pixel_array = red_collor;
        frame = true;
        px = 0;
        py = 0;

        var timer2 = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Background, Callback2, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
        var timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Callback1);
        timer1.Start();

        clock1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        t1 = clock1.ElapsedTicks;
    }

    private void Callback2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var t2 = clock1.ElapsedTicks;
        var fps = 10000000F / (t2 - t1) * frames_counter;
        Title = $"{fps:F1} fps";
        frames_counter = 0;
        t1 = t2;
    }

    private void Callback1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        writeableBitmap.WritePixels(single_pixel, single_pixel_array, 4, px, py);

        px++;
        if (px > 100)
        {
            px = 0;
            py++;
        }
        if (py > 100)
        {
            py = 0;
            single_pixel_array = frame ? blue_collor : red_collor;
            frame = !frame;
        }
        frames_counter++;
    }
}    enter code here
```

Comment: Just FYI: The DispatcherTimer is not a high resolution timer and is not guaranteed to be executed exactly when you want it to. Also, how are you measuring the amount of time it takes for a pixel to be drawn?

Comment: This approach does not rely on high precision in that part. Timer1 is set to zero interval, so it calls Callback1 as soon as possible. Callback1 has a counter. Timer2 is set to 1 second but could be any number. When Timer2 calls Callback2, I get the t2 time from the high resolution Clock1 and compares it with the previous t1 time Callback2 was called. Having the number of times Callback1 was executed and the time ( t2-t1 ) between the last two Callback2 calls, I get the average  frame rate in the last Timer2 period.